# How to evaluate $ \int_0^1 \frac{\tan^{-1}(x)}{x+1}dx = \frac{\pi}{8} \ln(2) $

Tags: integration

Does anyone know, how to evaluate following integral?

$$
\int_0^1 \frac{\tan^{-1}(x)}{x+1}dx = \frac{\pi}{8} \ln(2)
$$

There must be some nice trick, but I can't see it.

This integral is from the MIT Integration Bee 2021 Final Round.

I found the sheet online, but there is "only" the final result.

Thank you for helping.

Edit: My goal was not to be lazy or expect full solutions. A hint is enough.

Thanks to all helpers! :)

Comment: It is policy here for the asker to post attempts too, if help is expected. What did you try?

Comment: I know this.

I looked at wolframalpha for the indefinite integral. But there are "scary" functions showing up and I have no clue, why they appear.

I tried a couple of subs but all of them do not work nicely.

Comment: Ok, but how did you approach the problem?

Comment: The final answer makes me very much want to try integration by parts (integrating $1/x+1$).

Comment: There is actually a very sneaky substitution one can make by taking advantage of the inverse tangent identity$$\arctan x+\arctan y=\arctan\left(\frac {x+y}{1-xy}\right)$$(Stuff like this is exciting!!)

Comment: I have posted a hint. But kindly do edit the question and add your failed substitutions to it, to avoid downvotes and closure.

Comment: Oh ya... this is an obvious observation. :D
Sorry for that. Sometimes I can´t see the easiest relations after solving crazy integrals...

Comment: Okay, thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Enforce the substitution$$x=\frac {1-t}{1+t}\qquad\implies\qquad\mathrm dx=-\frac {2\,\mathrm dt}{(1+t)^2}$$

And observe what happens to$$\frac {\mathrm dx}{1+t}\mapsto f(t)\,\mathrm dt$$

Couple that with the inverse tangent identity$$\arctan x\pm\arctan y=\arctan\left(\frac {x\pm y}{1\mp xy}\right)$$
to reduce the integral into something much more easily manageable!

Comment: How do you come up with this "crazy" sustitution? Why you choose this one? :)

Comment: @easymathematics This is actually kind of an infamous substitution, I first learned it from one of Jack D'Aurizio's answers. Functions such as $\tfrac 1{1+x}$, $\tfrac 1{1+x^2}$, $\tfrac 1{\sqrt{x(1-x^2)}}$ do not change when the substitution takes place. This is mainly useful for $\arctan x$ since $\arctan\left(\tfrac {1-x}{1+x}\right)=\frac {\pi}4-\arctan x$ and when the limits are between $x=0$ and $x=1$

Answer (score 2):

$$I=\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\tan^{-1}x}{1+x} dx$$ Integrate by parts
$$I=\tan^{-1}{x}\ln(1+x)|_{0}^{1}-\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\ln(1+x)}{1+x^2} dx$$
$$\implies I=\frac{\pi}{4}\ln2-J$$
Let $x=\tan t$, then
$$J=\int_{0}^{\pi/4} \ln(1+\tan t) dt$$
Use $\int_{0}^{a} f(x) dx=\int_{0}^{a} f(a-x) dx$
Then $$J=\int_{0}^{\pi/4} \ln\left (1+\frac{1-\tan t}{1+\tan t}\right) dt=\frac{\pi}{4}\ln 2-J \implies J=\frac{\pi}{8}\ln 2.$$
Finally we have $$I=\frac{\pi}{8}\ln 2$$

Comment: Poo!! Let the OP figure it out! :(

Comment: True, OP didn't add any work in the question, so complete answers shouldn't be given.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: First apply IBP with $dv=\frac {1}{x+1}$ and $u=\tan^{-1} x$. Then it remains to evaluate the integral:
$$\int_{0}^1 \frac {\ln(1+x)}{x^2+1}\ dx$$
To obtain this substitute $x=\tan \theta$, and use the result that:
$$\int_{a}^b f(x)\ dx=\int_{a}^b f(a+b-x)\ dx$$

Comment: This is a big "Hint."